# ASP.NET no reconoce mis variables en mi url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

Tengo un metodo que espera un `int`

```js
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Municipios/{estado}")]
public ActionResult Municipios(int estado) {
    WebReference.CPAWS fx = new WebReference.CPAWS();
    var fxx = fx.WsExecuteMunicipios(estado);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fxx);
    var json2 = json.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@ "\", "
      ");
      return Json(json2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Entonces estoy tratando de mandarle esto

> https://localhost:44336/Mi/municipios/11

pero me devuelve este error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'estado' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Municipios(Int32)' in 'DashboardAdminFS_3.Controllers.MiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Nombre del parámetro: parameters

Alguien sabe que esta pasando?

Comment: Coloca tu startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la forma en que lo estás enviando no le das un nombre al parámetro por lo tanto la ruta asume que es `id` y no encuentra un valor con clave `estado`.

Prueba así: `/municipios/?estado=11`

O modifica la ruta:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Municipios/{id}")]
public ActionResult Municipios(int id) {
    WebReference.CPAWS fx = new WebReference.CPAWS();
    var fxx = fx.WsExecuteMunicipios(id);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fxx);
    var json2 = json.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@ "\", "
      ");
      return Json(json2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Actualización: Pasar múltiples parámetros**

Para enviar más parámetros solo agregalos a la url, por ejemplo:
`/municipios/11?param1=valor1&param2=valor2`

Para accederlos en la acción del controlador hay varias formas, una sería agregarlos a la lista de parámetros de la acción (nota que no necesitas modificar la ruta):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Municipios/{id}")]
public ActionResult Municipios(int id, string param1, string param2) {}
```

[Recurso adicional](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: Mil gracias, en plan, eres un genio :3

Comment: oye si quiero pasar dos parametros ocmo lo haría?

Comment: Agregué una actualización.